# add custom field having all locations for google map

Tags: wordpress

On the "Add new post" page i want to add new custom field having all the addresses. i want to use that address to show the activity on the google map against that address. like on the google map page there is a field from where we can select the address or location i want exact that type of custom field from where admin can select the location of the activity.

i am using Advanced Custom Fields plugin for adding custom field but i cannot add new custom field having all address or locations for google map.

Comment: what do you want say clearly

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, ACF does have a Google Maps integration that does very similar to what you're describing: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/google-map/